# Convergence of estimated Survival Functions

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, survival, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

[image]

Q1 part A&B  I have so far

$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty} {\lim} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nI(T_i>x)$$

since we are summing an indicator variable we can say it has a Bernoulli distribution with probability $P(T_i > x)$ call this $W_i$
so now we have  $$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty} {\lim} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$$

By the law of large numbers as our sample size n approaches infinity, our sample mean converges (in probability) to the population mean.

$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty} {\lim} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n W_i \rightarrow E(W_i)=S(x)$$ so the $$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty} {\lim} \tilde{S}(x) = S(x)$$

is it fair to say this as we are ignoring censoring. For the second 2 part are we to use the same logic?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Thanks, edit has been made